# Display only whole values along y axis in d3.js when range is 0-1 or 0-2

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3js to display a realtime representation of the views of a website. For this I use a stack layout and I update my dataset by JSON at the moment.

When there is only 1 or 2 views being displayed on the y axis, which is dynamic related to the amount of views in the graph, the axis labels are: 1 => `0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1`, the axis labels are: 2 => `0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2` This makes no sense for my dataset since it displays views of a page, and you can't have half a view.

I have a linear scale in d3js I base my y axis on

```
var y_inverted = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1]).rangeRound([0, height]);
```

According to [the documentation of rangeRound()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_rangeRound) I should only get whole values out of this scale. For drawing my axis I use:

```
var y_axis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(y_inverted.axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y_inverted)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5));
```

Because it is a realtime application I update this every second by calling:

```
function update(){
    y_inverted.domain([yStackMax, 0]);
    y_axis.transition()
        .duration(interval)
        .ease("linear")
        .call(y_inverted.axis);
}
```

yStackMax is calculated from a stacklayout, as far as I know the data used for the y values only contain integers.

```
var yStackMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) {
    return d3.max(layer, function(d) {
        return d.y0 + d.y;
    });
});
```

I have tried several things to get a proper value for my y axis.

```
d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y_inverted)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5).tickFormat(d3.format(",.0f"))
```

Got me the closest sofar, but it still displays `0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1`

Basically what I want is to only have 1 tick when `yStackMax` is 1, 2 ticks when it's 2, but it should also work if `yStackMax` is 12 or 1,000,000

Comment: btw., if you are happy with one of the answers, please accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short answer**: You can dynamically set the number of ticks. Set it to `1` to display only two tick labels:

```
var maxTicks = 5, minTicks = 1;
if (yStackMax < maxTicks) {
    y_axis.ticks(minTicks)
}
else {
    y_axis.ticks(maxTicks)
}
```

**Long Answer** (going a bit off topic):
While playing with your example I came up with a rather "complete solution" to all your  formatting problems. Feel free to use it :)

```
var svg = d3.select("#svg")
var width = svg.attr("width")
var height = svg.attr("height")
var yStackMax = 100000
var interval = 500
var maxTicks = 5
var minTicks = 1

var y_inverted = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1]).rangeRound([0, height])
var defaultFormat = d3.format(",.0f")

var format = defaultFormat

var y_axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y_inverted)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(minTicks)
    .tickFormat(doFormat)

var y_axis_root;
var decimals = 0;

function countDecimals(v){
    var test = v, count = 0;
    while(test > 10) {
        test /= 10
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

function doFormat(d,i){
    return format(d,i)
}

function init(){
    y_axis_root = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        // I modified your example to move the axis to a visible part of the screen
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,0)")
        .call(y_axis)
}

// custom formatting functions:
function toTerra(d) { return (Math.round(d/10000000000)/100) + "T" }
function toGiga(d)  { return (Math.round(d/10000000)/100) + "G" }
function toMega(d)  { return (Math.round(d/10000)/100) + "M" }
function toKilo(d)  { return (Math.round(d/10)/100) + "k" }

// the factor is just for testing and not needed if based on real world data
function update(factor){
    factor = (factor) || 0.1;
    yStackMax*=factor
    decimals = countDecimals(yStackMax)
    console.log("yStackMax decimals:",decimals, factor)
    if     (yStackMax < maxTicks) {
        format = defaultFormat
        y_axis.ticks(minTicks)
    }
    else {
        y_axis.ticks(maxTicks)
        if     (decimals < 3 ) format = defaultFormat
        else if(decimals < 6 ) format = toKilo
        else if(decimals < 9 ) format = toMega
        else if(decimals < 12) format = toGiga
        else                   format = toTerra
    }

    y_inverted.domain([yStackMax, 0]);
    y_axis_root.transition()
        .duration(interval)
        .ease("linear")
        .call(y_axis);
}

init()
setTimeout(update, 200)
setTimeout(update, 400)
setTimeout(update, 600)
```

You can try it together with this html snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div><svg id="svg" width="200" height="300"></svg></div>
        <script src="axis.js"></script>
        <button id="button1" onclick="update(10)">+</button>
        <button id="button2" onclick="update(0.1)">-</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know it is a bit off topic but I usually like to provide running examples/solutions. Regard the additional formatting stuff as a bonus to the actual problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you ask for a certain number of ticks (via axis.ticks() ) then d3 will try to give you that many ticks - but will try to use pretty values. It has nothing to do with your data.

Your solutions are to use tickFormat, as you did, to round all the values to integer values, only ask for one tick as Juve answered, or explicitly set the tick values using [axis.tickValues([...])](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues) which would be pretty easy used in conjunction with [d3.range](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_range)

rangeRound will not help in this case because it relates to the output range of the scale, which in this case is the pixel offset to plot at: between 0 and height.

Answer (score 4):

Going off of Superboggly's answer, this is what worked for me. First I got the max (largest) number from the y domain using `y.domain().slice(-1)[0]` and then I built an array of tick values from that using `d3.range()`...

```
  var y_max = y.domain().slice(-1)[0]
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .tickValues(d3.range(y_max+1))
      .tickFormat(d3.format(",.0f"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just let the ticks as they are and "hide" decimal numbers

```
d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y_inverted)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5).tickFormat(function(d) {
              if (d % 1 == 0) {
                return d3.format('.f')(d)
              } else {
                return ""
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));
```