# Adding commas to large numbers in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, string-formatting

I have data points on a line, when the cursor passes over them, a tooltip div appears with data about that point. The code for the html of the div is below.

```
    div.html("The Avengers Box Office: $" + d.Avengers)
```

d.Avengers returns 207438708 as a string. So is there any way to add commas to large numbers in d3.js?

I have values ranging from thousands to hundreds of millions and it can be tricky to read them.

Thanks

Comment: can u show some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the replies guys. I found the answer here. Its not adding commas, but its adding M or K after millions or thousands. Which is actually better I think.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/YFsSmzu4JZk

Comment: To do commas as the thousands delimiter in d3, you can do almost the same thing, just add a comma in your d3 format, something like `myFormat = d3.format(',')`. Then apply `myFormat` to the text you want to separate with commas. `myFormat(1000000)` returns 1,000,000

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**:
You can't add commas using d3 but you can do via plain JavaScript: [Number.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```
// convert Avengers to a Number and use the toLocaleString on it
div.html("The Avengers Box Office: $" + (1*d.Avengers).toLocaleString() )
```

**Advanced Solution**: If your main problem is that numbers are just too big (even with commas), you need write some really cool conversion functions for your numbers that

1. count the decimals and
2. choose a really nice format to display nice numbers

Check out a somehow [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513177/display-only-whole-values-along-y-axis-in-d3-js-when-range-is-0-1-or-0-2/13531659#13531659) where I added some code to do that, converting big numbers to "kilo", "mega", "giga", and "terra". You might want to adopt that.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I found the answer here

Answer (score -1):

d3.format(',')(1999222) //// output=1,999,222